# First day of the next month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-date-functions

I'm trying get the results where it only displays OrderDates before the LAST day of the CURRENT month.
I'm guessing it would be like this...

```
SELECT OrderDate
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate < (code for first day of the next month?)
```

Comment: please search SO before posting a question: asked many times previously

Comment: So you can have orders in the future? Just want to check that you do intend to support post-dating these and that you're not making the problem harder than it needs to be when you could just look at current_timestamp.

Answer (score 76):

First day of next month:

sql-server 2012+

```
DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(current_timestamp))
```

sql-server 2008 and older:

```
DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, -1, current_timestamp), 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is somewhat ambiguous, but this will give you '(code for the first day of the month)'

```
SELECT OrderDate
FROM Orders 
WHERE ORDERDATE < DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Comment: I think he wants first day of next month, but for that all you need to do is add a +1 after the closing paren for the DATEDIFF() call, so close enough.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate())+1, 0) AS StartOfMonth
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's understand the method to get first day of current month, we can fetch day component from the date (e.g. @mydate) using DATEPART and subtract this day component to get last day of previous month. Add one day to get first day of current month.
E.g. @mydate = 10/8/2019, subtract day component (8 days) will give us 9/30/2019. Now add one day in this outcome to get first of the current month - 10/1/2019.

Formula - DATEADD(day,1,DATEADD(day, -DATEPART(day,@mydate), @mydate))

**Now First of the next month** - Add one month in above formula
DATEADD(month,1,(DATEADD(day,1,DATEADD(day, -DATEPART(day,@mydate), @mydate))))

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT OrderDate
FROM Orders 
WHERE ORDERDATE < DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,getdate()))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,getdate()))
```

Take a look at [here](http://sqlandme.com/2011/05/16/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-a-month-tsql/)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OrderDate FROM Orders WHERE orderdate < (LAST_DAY(CURRENT DATE) + 1)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select Convert(date,Dateadd(dd,1 - DATEPART(dd,getdate()), DATEADD(mm,1,getdate())),103)
```

Comment: While this code may/may not solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations.

Answer (score 0):

For sql-server 2012 ->

Using DateFromParts will do the trick. +1 to get the next month

```
SELECT OrderDate
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(Getdate()),MONTH(Getdate())+1,1)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql