# SQL update date to first of next month plus three months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have this query:

```
  update courseRights
         set courseRightsLevelExpires = DATEADD(MM,3,courseRightsLevelExpires)
```

This works fine but what I actually need is to extend to three months from the first day of next month. For example if the rights are expiring today, May 23rd, I need to update to June 1st + 3 months.

Is it possible to do that in one query?

### Update

Because it was flagged as duplicate with another question, I'm updating the content to say that I'm not only looking for the first date of next month but I need to add three months to that date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First day of the next month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623971/first-day-of-the-next-month)

Comment: Its not a possible duplicate @TabAlleman my requirements were a bit different as you can see from my question. Thanks

Comment: The difference being that you need to add 3 months?    From your posted code it looks like you already know how to do that.

Comment: But I didn't know how to combine both functions which was answered in the answers below

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656367/sql-get-first-day-of-month-3-months-before-current-month?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eomoth(`) function :

```
update courseRights
set courseRightsLevelExpires = 
    dateadd(mm, 3, dateadd(dd, 1, eomonth(courseRightsLevelExpires)));
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the first day of next month:

```
DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, -1, current_timestamp), 0)
```

Three month's after that:

```
DATEADD(m,3,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, -1, current_timestamp), 0))
```

So, if `courseRightsLevelExpires` holds the base date you're working from:

```
DATEADD(m,3,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, -1, courseRightsLevelExpires), 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do:

set nextmonthdate = last_day (your-date) + 1 day

Comment: your solution is not clear enough, add a description of it and tell how it's going to solve the problem, please.

Comment: Here what I wound do:

Comment: You can use function LAST_DAY. It will give you the last day of any given date. Adding 1 day to that will give you the 1st day of the following month and then add 3 months to the resut.  e.g.:     update courseRights
set courseRightsLevelExpires = (LAST_DAY('yyyy-mm-dd') + 1 day) + 3 MONTHS

Comment: update courseRights
         set courseRightsLevelExpires = (LAST_DAY(courseRightsLevelExpires) + 1 DAY) + 3 MONTHS